# Keyboard shortcut to restore active view in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse-cdt

There is a shortcut for minimizing and maximizing, but not for restoring[image: Restore]

Comment: There is an open bug, but someone needs to provide a contribution, or highlight it again as no one is looking at it: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=344151

Comment: Thank you, I will try to make my interest on the bug noted

Comment: You should also probably "vote" on that issue. ;-)